# C# Currency to string

Tags: c#

I am querying a database field that returns a money value, I am assigning this to a string but it is adding extra 00 on the end.

e.g. Query returns `30.00`

I assign this to a string (`string value = Convert.ToString(ReturnValue);`)
but when I output it, it is showing as `30.0000`

Can you advise me where I'm going wrong and the best way to approach this?

Comment: What is the .NET type of the variable that you are getting back from your database (before you convert to string)?

Comment: The OP can use the string formatting codes, that's what they are there for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [string format codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) in your ToString call.

Answer (score 15):

MartGriff,

My best advice would be to convert it to a double using the SqlMoney type.  From there, you can output it however you would like!

Here's an example:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlMoney ReturnValue;

//Set your returnValue with your SQL statement
ReturnValue = ExecuteMySqlStatement();

//Get the format you want

//$30.00
string currencyFormat = ReturnValue.ToDouble().ToString("c");

//30.00
string otherFormat = ReturnValue.ToDouble().ToString("0.00");
```

For more formatting options, check out the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring.aspx

Best of luck, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want your string formatted using a currency character?

If so...

```
decimal m = 3.4;

string s = string.Format("{0:c}", m);

// s will be £3.40, $3.40, etc depending on your locale settings
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like

```
string value = ReturnValue.ToString("0.00");
```

This uses the ToString overload that accepts a format string.
The above format string "0.00" specifies two decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently developing a boatdock web system, using VS 2013 Community edition. I was trying to work out how to output a currency value into a textbox.

The method that I used was

fieldName.Text = decimalValue.ToString("c");

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourValueHere.ToString("0.00")
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to convert it to Decimal firstly. I'd use something like this:

```
string value = (Convert.ToDecimal(ReturnValue)).ToString("0,0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer a money data type is the equivalent of a decimal with 4 decimal places of precision. I would assume this is precision is conserved when the decimal is converted to a string. The best option would be to always use a format string eg "#,##0.00" when doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The Money data type has a precision of 4 decimal places.  You'll need to either specify the format in the ToString() arguments or you can round off the value before converting to a string.

If you use .ToString() you're not getting any rounding as far as I know.  I think you just lose the digits.

If you round, you're not just chopping off digits.  Here's a sample for rounding (untested code):

```
string value = Math.Round(ReturnValue, 2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = (Convert.ToDecimal(ReturnValue)).ToString("c");
```

c is for currency
p for percentage.
There is [a list of other letters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) you can use.